# Incorrect lat / lon conversion from utm

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgis-2.0, shp2pgsql

I used [this website](http://prj2epsg.org/search) to determine that the SRID for my shapefile is 3857.  Following that information, I used the `shp2pgsql` utility to convert my shapefile into the sql I need to insert into PostreSQL (using PostGIS):

`shp2pgsql -s 3857 /my.shp > /my.sql`

The data was inserted properly into Postgres giving me a `geom` column of type `geometry(Point, 3857)`, which is what I expected.

My issue is that when I run the following query to get the lat / lon value, they don't give me the proper coordinates.  Here's my query:

`select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 3857), 4326)) from mytable limit 1;`

The problem is that it gives me a latitude and longitude that points to a random location in India, when I know in fact that this should be pointing to a location in the United States.

It's worth noting that when I use the `ogr2ogr` utility to convert my shapefile to GeoJSON, it maps out all of the coordinates correctly, so the shapefile itself seems to be in proper order.

Here are some untransformed points from a basic `ST_AsText` query: `POINT(-10683225.3808045 3373544.37856286)`

Comment: EPSG:3857 is not utm, but Pseudo Mercator. Can you try without ST_SetSRID, because you have already set the SRID when importing.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a couple of the (untransformed) points?

Comment: I've added untransformed points.  I've also tried not specifying `ST_SetSRID` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the issue...  I scanned through other shapefiles I have that are related and noticed that their SRID is set to `2278`.  I inputted that for the current shapefile and I'm getting the correct coordinates now.  Someone probably messed it up in ArcGIS or similar beforehand.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You should mark you answer right :)